# How to invalidate layout of a uicollectionview within the uicollectionviewcell of a parent uicollectionview?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout

Here's the [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRbYW.jpg) I have.

I have a UICollectionView that has UICollectionViews embedded in its cells. On the iPad, when I rotate the screen, I can invalidate the layout of the parent UICollectionView by overriding

```
func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

This works just fine. However, I am not sure how to redirect this trigger to the UICollectionViews inside the individual cells.

So far, I have tried to invalidate the layout of those UICollectionViews thru `func layoutSubviews()`. This is not very consistent as some cells are still with old layout. However, this:

```
func willTransition(from oldLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, to newLayout: UICollectionViewLayout)
```

doesn't get triggered at all for this scenario.

I have also tried `func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool` in the flow layout for the embedded UICollectionViews.

I'm not using self-sizing cells, i.e., I'm providing the size of the cells through

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

What's the cleanest way to solve this to have consistent results?

Appreciate any pointers in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the following method **within each UIView of the parent cell**?

```
override public func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
            super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
```

Comment: I’ve tried that and it doesn’t seem to get triggered at all as I believe the iPad size factor is the same for both landscape and portrait — i.e., “Regular”

Comment: @rajendra.prabhu
In the method, "public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell", did you do:
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell... 
let theTargetView = cell.contentView as? YourTargetView
...
Then in the YourTargetView class, you implement the method traitCollectionDidChange...?